# How to compare two strings by ignoring between two indexes via python or regex

Tags: python, regex, string-comparison

**Language:** Python 3.

I am quite interested to know how to compare the below strings by ignoring the value of object "DateandTime" as it will never be the same. Hence, that alone to be ignored during comparison.

```
Str1='''{"Name":"Denu","Contact":12345678, "DateandTime":20200207202019}'''

Str2= '''{"Name":"Denu","Contact":12345678, "DateandTime":20200207220360}'''
```

Any help would be indeed appreciated.

Comment: What have you come up with so far?

Comment: These are not strings. These are dictionaries. How exactly do you want to compare them? Show some inputs with expected outputs and what you tried so far and what goes wrong with that

Comment: @Tomerikoo I would want to compare after converting dict to string.

Comment: Why? It would make it much harder. You just need to specify the compare criteria so we know what you're trying to do

Comment: @Tomerikoo I am getting two json files to compare in my project. Few scenarios where value of the object would be different all the times like the one I have specified. So that value alone to be ignored during comparison. Secondly few more objects and its values will also get appended in one json. I am trying to learn how to work on the first part now.

Comment: Please clarify your question. The code makes very little sense, too, and there is no evidence that you've actually tried to solve this. Looking at the accepted answer, this was a trivial/basic issue anyway, so I'm voting to close this.

Comment: Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may easily create an identical function using the dicts in the first place. Don't convert it to a string as it already is a usable object.

```
Str1 = {"Name":"Denu","Contact":12345678, "DateandTime":20200207202019}
Str2 = {"Name":"Denu", "Contact":12345678, "DateandTime":20200207220360}

def isidentical(dct1, dct2):
    """ Compares two dicts for equality """

    ignore = ["DateandTime"]

    keys1 = set(key for key in dct1 if not key in ignore)
    keys2 = set(key for key in dct2 if not key in ignore)

    if keys1 != keys2:
        return False

    for key in keys1:
        if dct1[key] != dct2[key]:
            return False
    return True

x = isidentical(Str1, Str2)
print(x)
# True in this case
```

This will throw an error if one dictionary has other keys than the other one or if the values are not identical. Obviously, you could extend the `ignore` list.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) keys **except** the one you don't care about are equal:

```py
def eq(d1, d2):
    keys = set(d1.keys())
    keys.update(d2.keys())
    return all(d1.get(k) == d2.get(k) for k in keys if k != "DateandTime")

d1 = {"Name": "Denu", "Contact": 12345678, "DateandTime": 20200207202019}
d2 = {"Name": "Denu", "Contact": 12345678, "DateandTime": 20200207220360}

print(eq(d1, d2))
```

This prints `True`.